# Can buffer boundaries be displayed at the top and bottom of windows?

Tags: window, scrolling

I know that Emacs can [display the buffer boundaries in the fringe](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Displaying-Boundaries.html), by displaying angles at the boundaries, and arrows where the buffer can be scrolled. Is there some way to display these boundaries, and scroll status, at the top and bottom of a buffer? I’m hoping for an effect like that seen in Symbolics Genera. Take a look at this screenshot of Genera’s Document Examiner for an example:

[image: Symbolics Genera Document Examiner]

The main Document Examiner window is scrolled part way through the document, with neither the top nor bottom boundaries visible. As such, both the top and bottom of the window display a torn-sheet effect, similar to a string of tilde characters ie. `~~~~~~~~~~`.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, Emacs can display one line at the top of each window (the header line) and one at the bottom (the mode line). By default the header line isn't used for anything but some packages make use of it.

It would be possible to configure the header line and (parts of) the mode line to display a suitable character depending on which portions of the window is visible. For example, the mode line already contains an identifier displaying "Top", "NN%", or "Bot".